# certain custom font get cut off on TextView

Tags: android, layout, fonts, textview

I use official font of seoul city in my app. (`Namsan font`) 
there are total 5 namsan font file.

1. `font_namsan_medium.otf`
2. `font_namsan_bold.otf`
3. `font_namsan_extrabold.otf`
4. `font_namsan_black.otf`
5. `font_namsan_light.otf`

I have created font resource folder, and font resource xml file to apply font

**res/font/namsan_medium.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:font="@font/font_namsan_medium"
        app:font="@font/font_namsan_medium" />
</font-family>
```

and, I used `android:fontFamily` to apply font resource in `TextView`

**layout/activity_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.SplashActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/namsan_black"
        android:text="Hello Custom Font"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But, when I use only `namsan_medium.otf`, text is get cut off in textview.

please refer to below screen shot.

[image]

in case of the other fonts except `namsan_medium.otf`, displayed well.

[image]

Is there a solution I can try in this case?

1. Could there be a problem with the font itself?
2. Is this android side effect?

I think this is a problem caused by the failure to calculate the exact size of TextView when the font is applied. Therefore, when I set TextView's width and height to MATCH_CONSTRAINT, there is no problem. But I don't want to do that just for a certain font.

---

I attach screen shot (enable drawing options)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried giving padding in your textview? 

Seems like an issue with the font to me.

Comment: yes. I tried to giving padding in textview. but same problem. If it's a font problem, is there no way to solve it?

Comment: I have seen several issues where wrapping your textview inside a Flexbox layout solved the problem, you can try that too and let me know if that doesn't work either.

Comment: Please enable layout boundaries option described here and attach a screenshot (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#drawing)

Please also try to use another layout (i.e. a framelayout) to isolate the problem to see if it is the layout or the textview, or the behavior with a certain layout.

Comment: @JaswantSingh ok. i will immediately try it.

Comment: @Siyamed I update screen shot. and it's all same problem in the other layouts